# How to use oracle sequence while insert/update in SAS DI 4.8

Tags: oracle, dependency-injection, sas, sequence

I'm joining a sybase table and a sas data set to insert/update data using a table loader in oracle. The table ID needs to be loaded using a sequence which resides in oracle. Can you please let me know how to use an oracle sequence to generate a ID column? I tried adding a dummy column to the same oracle table joined it to the result set and tried specifying seqname.nextval in a expression editor but getting an error:

ERROR: Unresolved reference to table/correlation name seqname.

Comment: More help would be available if you show your code

Comment: Hi Crowne, 

I am using sas table loader transformation.. The code is joining couple of table in SAS DI..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this kind of oracle-specific functionality with DI Studio you will need to use a custom code step and write the SQL yourself within a 'proc sql' passthrough statement.

If the code is to be re-used in several places you also have the option to write it as a DI transformation.